# Undefined offset error after using array_filter PHP

Tags: php, explode, array-filter

I previously had a with counting the array after exploding it, which was solved using `array_filter` but now when i echo the elements on the array it gives me undefined offset error

```
$exclude=array();
$exclude[0]="with";
$exclude[1]="do";

$search="moving on with my car";
$sch1 = str_replace($exclude,"", trim($search));
$sch2 = explode(" ",trim($sch1));
$sch = array_filter($sch2);
// The value of the count is actually 4

// But when i try to display throws an indefined offset error
echo $sch[0]; 
echo $sch[1]; 
echo $sch[2]; // Throwing an "Undefined offset: 2" Error
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: please show what you wnat output? you have replaced $sch[2]; with ""

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to output "moving on my car", and its been solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) removes all entries of the array that equals `FALSE`, thereby creating a gap in your array.

This is what `$sch2` contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => moving
    [1] => on
    [2] => 
    [3] => my
    [4] => car
)
```

When you apply `array_filter()` on `$sch2`, you'll get an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => moving
    [1] => on
    [3] => my
    [4] => car
)
```

As you can see, index `2` is ***not*** defined. You need to re-index the array numerically for this to work. You can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) for this purpose:

```
$sch = array_values(array_filter($sch2));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/116019)

Comment: thanks, i also checked myself now and its jst as u've said it, its true..will be chosen as answer